# searching in postgres tsvector for something with `-` in does not work

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres `tsvector` label field which contains

'hello-world' 'hungry'

now we let the user search for these terms and brings them back for example they can search for explict labels..

Everytime a user tries to search with a `-` it does not return

does not work:

```
  SELECT 
    labels
  FROM tbt
  WHERE labels @@ to_tsquery('hello-world | jobs')
```

works:

```
  SELECT 
    labels
  FROM tbt
  WHERE labels @@ to_tsquery('hungry | jobs')
```

How can i make `-` work in the tsquery search as well?

I would like to achieve this in the query and not have to change any data in the tables.

thanks in advance!

explained all in the above

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have bypassed the to_tsvector in constructing your tsvector, you should also bypass to_tsquery and generate the tsquery directly.  For example, this yields true:

```
select 'hello-world'::tsvector @@ 'hello-world | foo'::tsquery;
```